# collect a value per console and multiply powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to collect a value per console, in this case an ip address, and that the suffix of this is self-incrementally and multiplied by line up to 254.
I tried with for, but this create each file text. thats my code.

```
$ipaddress=$args[0]
New-Item .\direcciones.txt -Force 
$filetext= New-Item .\direcciones.txt -Force 
for ($i=1, $i -le 254;)
{ Add-Content -Path $filetext -Value $ipaddress.$i }
```

i expect something like the filetext:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
...
192.168.1.254
```

the autoincrement value that i want is the last octet and the 3 first is the $arg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to **enclose `$ipaddress.$i` in `"..."`**; additionally, you can streamline your code:

```bash
1..254 | ForEach-Object { "$ipaddress.$_" } | Set-Content $filetext
```

Or, more efficiently, but more obscurely:

```bash
1..254 -replace '^', "$ipaddress." | Set-Content $filetext
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- (This may just be a posting artifact) `for ($i=1, $i -le 254;)` creates an *infinite* loop, because you're missing `; ++$i` for *incrementing* the iterator variable `$i`.
- Even in [argument-parsing mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), `$ipaddress.$i` - in the absence of enclosure in `"..."` - is interpreted as an *expression*, meaning that `$i` is interpreted as the name of a *property* to access on `$ipaddress`, which therefore results in `$null`, so that no data is written to the output file.
- Only inside an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) - i.e. `"$ipaddress.$i"` in this case - are `$ipaddress` and `$i` expanded *individually*.

Comment: Just what i need it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SergioSánchez; my pleasure.